# Error with terraform template for Azure provioning

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create a VM with terraform (version 0.9.3) azurerm provisioner but getting generic error ***not a valid plan file***.
This is happening with both ***apply*** and ***plan*** option.

I tried the same with terraform version 0.8.2 and the error message changed to ***Error loading config: configuration path must be a directory:***

I am not sure what is wrong here. Below is the template that I am executing.
Appreciate any help on this.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    subscription_id = "${var.my_subscription_id}"
    client_id       = "${var.my_client_id}"
    client_secret   = "${var.my_client_secret}"
    tenant_id       = "${var.my_tenant_id}"
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "terraform_rg" {
    name     = "terraform_rg"
    location = "West US"
    tags {
        name = "terraformpoc"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "terraform_sg" {
    name                = "terraformSG1"
    location            = "West US"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.terraform_rg.name}"
    security_rule {
        name                       = "SGRule"
        priority                   = 100
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "*"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
    }
    tags {
        name = "terraformpoc"
    }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "terraform_ni" {
    name                = "terraforminstni"
    location            = "West US"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.terraform_rg.name}"
    network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.terraform_sg.id}"
    enable_ip_forwarding = true
    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "terraformtestconfig"
        subnet_id                     = "${var.my_subnet}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "terraform_vm" {
    name                  = "terraforminstvm"
    location              = "West US"
    resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.terraform_rg.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.terraform_ni.id}"]
    vm_size               = "Standard_A0"
    delete_data_disks_on_termination  = true
    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer     = "UbuntuServer"
        sku       = "14.04.2-LTS"
        version   = "latest"
    }

    storage_os_disk {
        name          = "myosdisk1"
        caching       = "ReadWrite"
        create_option = "FromImage"
    }   

    os_profile {
        computer_name  = "hostname"
        admin_username = "${var.my_admin_username}"
        admin_password = "${var.my_admin_password}"
    }

    os_profile_linux_config {
        disable_password_authentication = false
    }

    tags {
        name = "terraformpoc"
    }
}
```

Comment: What command are you trying to run?

Comment: I tried both *terraform apply /path/to/above/tf* and *terraform plan /path/to/above/tf* but same error in both cases - **not a valid plan file**

Comment: Terraform should be pointed at a _folder_ not a file. So you should be running `terraform plan /path/to/above`. It will then concatenate all .tf files in the folder and execute them all in one go.

Comment: Thank you! This resolved it! I was trying to run it on file.